# Is there a Community Detection algorithm that has low time complexity such as Louvain, but that penalizes TOO large of communities

Tags: python, machine-learning, graph, networkx, modularity

I am building a massive network, that is filled with isolated nodes, but also rather large clusters as well. I have used Louvain's algorithm to achieve the best partition - however some communities are too large. I was curious what algorithms (preferably with Python frameworks) have similar run time to Louvain but penalize too large of communities while achieving ideal modularity?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to iterate the community detection algorithm (Louvain or other) by running it on the too large communities you first find. This will partition them into smaller ones.

Notice also that Louvain and other community detection algorithms generally do not produce *the best* partition, but *a good* partition with respect to a given quality function. In most cases, finding the best partition is NP-hard.

With this in mind, one may include a *scale* parameter into the quality function, and detect relevant community at different scales: [Post-Processing Hierarchical Community Structures: Quality Improvements and Multi-scale View](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0608050)